# call phone with extension fails on android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, phone-call

trying to call phone, say tel:01234567,1815 where the extension is 1815 and comma is the pause.

this fails in all three ways 1) using an intent, 2) autolink a text field and 3)using openurl.

in most cases it passes the pure phone number to the dialpad, but not the complete number with the extension. i need this to directly go into a conference room.

permission CALL_PHONE has been set in manifest as well a checked during runtime in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try [PhoneNumberUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html).PAUSE or PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s%s%s","01234567",PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE,"#1815"));
```

or
  
  
  `callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s%s%s","01234567",PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT,"#1815"));`

Comment: thanks for the hint. i had two issues. in my code the intent was never called, instead the openurl code was always called. and secondly i was under the impression, that the extension was also displayed in the phone app. instead the number is called and then SILENTLY the extension is dialed. i could only hear the result from the IVR.